# Mp3 files; constant frame "specs"

Tags: variables, mp3, frames

I'm playing with mp3 files and, could not find in the specification
whether, except for the bitrate, the characteristics of the frames
are allowed to variate. 
Out of about 17k files I've tested my program on, I've found a few 
where the layer and channel mode switch mid-stream. Are those
corrupt files or is it allowed?
It appeared from my tests that sampling rate and frame duration stay 
constant, but maybe it's just true with the files I tested.

Anyone knows anything about variable characteristics of frames, besides VBR?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short Version: Either your frame parser is losing sync and reading compressed audio data as a frame header, or you are seeing files that were originally two different MPEG streams that have been concatenated together.

TL;DR:
MP3 generally expects frames to be consistent in layer, channel count (notice I didn't say "mode"), & sample rate for any given stream.  The spec doesn't say "These must be consistent in the stream" or anything like that, but it does define a decoder that pretty well requires them to stay consistent for proper operation.  Other fields can generally change from frame to frame, though only bit rate index and channel mode / sub-mode are likely to change.

Comment: Can't vote up since I don't have enough rep but I like that answer. I've checked the frame parsing and it is not the problem. There is a sequence of about 2 secs where it switches from mpeg 1 layer 3 to mpeg 2 layer 3 but the frame sequence is not broken. The sound gets choppy though but my program only analyses the stream, not the audio content. Thanks

Comment: Glad it worked out.  Switching from v1 to v2 is very strange; Are you sure they don't have bit errors?  Either way, you should be able to accept the answer, which would be much appreciated. :)